# ANOVA in R: How MSresiduals are estimated when using Error(interaction)?

Tags: anova, error, sums-of-squares

I have checked the existing answers, but I found no answer to my question. It is about choosing the right ANOVA model in R and how the MSresiduals are estimated.

I have an experiment with two factors: `MANAGEMENT` and `REGION`. I have three `MANAGEMENT` types and three `REGIONS`. That means nine sites under study but no repetition, like this:

`REGION`: `A`, `B` and `C` (those regions are not clonal copies of each other)
`MANAGEMENT`: `N`, `P`, `ST`
the dependent variable is called `PHt`

I have set the `aov` in R in two possible ways.

Model1: `aov(PHt~REGION+MANAGEMENT+REGION*MANAGEMENT, data=data)`

Model2: `aov(PHt~REGION*MANAGEMENT+Error(subject/(REGION*MANAGEMENT)),data=data)`

In respect to these two models I have three questions:

1. Is it correct that the second model should be used if we aim to include the interaction term into the `Error` term?
2. How does the model 2 estimate the MSresiduals? It seems to use different MSresiduals for each variable. Why? (See output for both models below.)
3. Since I have unbalanced data, is R using an approximation of a Wald test?

Here are results of the two models.

```
Model 1
Model <- aov(PHt~REGION+MANAGEMENT+REGION*MANAGEMENT, data=data)
summary(model)
                    Df      Sum Sq        Mean Sq    F value       Pr(>F)    
REGION               2      0.05          0.0229       0.907        0.4039    
MANAGEMENT           2      0.18          0.0884       3.494        0.0306 *  
REGION:MANAGEMENT    4      3.34          0.8351      33.021        <2e-16 ***
Residuals           1744    44.10         0.0253              

Model 2
aov(PHt~REGION*MANAGEMENT+Error(subject/(REGION*MANAGEMENT)),data=data)

SUMMARY:
  Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Residuals 195  4.714 0.02494               

Error: subject_f:REGION
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
REGION      2  0.066 0.03281   1.406  0.246
Residuals 388  8.822 0.02334               

Error: subject_f:MANAGEMENT
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
MANAGEMENT   2  0.205 0.10260   4.413 0.0127 *
Residuals  388  8.788 0.02325                 
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: subject_f:REGION:MANAGEMENT
                   Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
REGION:MANAGEMENT   4  3.451  0.8627   31.99 <2e-16 ***
Residuals         776 20.389  0.0270                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, `PHt` is your dependent variable, not independent variable. In addition, your model 1 can simply be written as `aov(PHt~REGION*MANAGEMENT,data=data)` because the `*` symbol denotes both main effects and interaction. If you want interaction only, it should be `REGION:MANAGEMENT`. See `?formula` for more detail.

Now I will try to answer your 3 questions in reverse order.

**A3:** 
The fact that the design is unbalanced really suggests you should be using mixed model (unless it is very close to being balanced, then perhaps you can stay with `aov`) Google the R package `nlme` for fitting mixed model.

**A2:**
The MS for Residuals in each error stratum (`subject_f:REGION`, then `subject_f:MANAGEMENT`, then `subject_f:REGION:MANAGEMENT`) is trying to estimate the variability attributed to that specific stratum. So the first MSResidual, 0.02334, is saying `subject_f:REGION` adds $\sigma^2\approx 0.02334^2$ to the total variability in the data, while `subject_f:MANAGEMENT` adds approximately $0.02325^2$ to the total variation in data. Since they are different factors that add to the total variability, it makes sense that they are different.

**A1:**
I am actually not very sure what you are asking. I guess the surface answer is yes, if you want to include the interaction term in the `Error()` term, then it is correct to 'include the interaction term in the `Error()` term'. However, is this really what you want? It is not immediately clear to me that `MANAGEMENT` should appear in the `Error()` term. I am not saying it can't be the case, but are you sure that's what you want? Also, what is the interpretation of `subject/MANAGEMENT*REGION`?

I personally would suggest that you consult your local statistical expert. But if you really must do it yourself, then perhaps [read up](http://stat.bell-labs.com/NLME/UGuide.pdf) on mixed model?